# Access secure information from a backend server using Android

Tags: android, mysql, security, access-token, android-keystore

I am making a trivia android application, and I have the questions and answers database stored on my server. In my app, the user types in his/her username and password, and this is sent to a servlet, which then authenticates it with the Database. If the authentication was successful, the user information for the particular user will be downloaded and stored in SharedPreferences. In the user information, there is a user key that is used to access the server again to update user information, and get other values from the database such as the questions and answers. However, this is not very secure as any attacker can create an account, login, and find the user key and use it to get the trivia answers. Should I use a keystore or a token system in my server to authenticate a request for the database. How should I do this? Thanks for the help!

Answer (score 0):

You could scramble the key before putting it in shared pref, and then unscramble it before sending it to your server each time... not to say someone couldn't reverse engineer your app to look at your algorithm and figure out the real key. But then again, how hard are people really going to try to cheat at trivia?

Comment: You'd be surprised, people cheat at ProgressQuest.

Answer (score 0):

The most secure way would be not to send the answers.  Send the user's answer to the server, and have the server check the answer and return right or wrong.

Comment: I have an access key which allows me to gain access to the server. Where should I store this key, and how?

Answer (score 0):

Use PGP encryption. Encrypt user/pw using public key in android then decrypt it using private key in the server. mcrypt or openssl can do that for you.